# Refresh adding an extra parameter

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I need to refresh the webpage, but in the refresh request I want to add an extra parameter, so I have though in something like:

```
<c:url value="currentUrl" var="newUrl">
    <c:param name="newParam" value="newValue"/>
</c:url>
<a href="${newUrl}">Refresh</a>
```

How can I get the **currentUrl with the params** (for instance http://localhost:8080/mywebapp?param1=var1&param2=var2) of the request from the implicit objects of the jsp.
I have though in something like ${pageContext.request.requestURL}, but this returns the url of the jsp, not the request url.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the JSP has been forwarded, you can get the original request URL by `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}` and the original request query string by
`${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}`.

You can by the way find an overview of all those "hidden" forward attributes [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagi.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI).

Comment: @Thanks, this let me get the url without params, but it's useful

Comment: You really know it deep down :) +1

Comment: @Javi: Try the same with this, `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}`

Comment: Indeed, use this to get the original query string as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Based on [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323316/refresh-adding-an-extra-parameter/4324470#4324470)**

You can try these two,

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}
${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}
```

**JavaScript Approach**

Do you mean the URL in address bar? If that’s the case you can write a JavaScript function to get the parameters and then modify your `href` in question.

For example,

```
<a id="refresh" href="${newUrl}">Refresh</a>
...

var url = window.location.href;
url += url.split("?").length > 1 ? "&newParam=value" : "?newParam=value";
document.getElementById("refresh").href = url;
```

It would much shorter, if you are using jQuery or PrototypeJS like JavaScript framework.

Comment: yeah, I had already thought about it too, thanks, but I thought a solution based on jsp would be cleaner. The problem of changing it in javascript is that I couldn't use <c:url/> tag, so I have to check manually for "?" character to see if there are params in the url to add "?newParam=value" or "&newParam=value". Is there something in javascript which would add params in a clean way to urls?

Comment: @Javi: `window.location.href += window.location.href.split("?").length > 1 ? "?newParam=value" : "?newParam=value"`

Comment: that would work, though I'm still curious if it could be done without javascript, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Javi: I updated my post using BalusC's answer. Give it a try if that solves your problem in a better way.